# I'm trying to find a periodic orbit using the shooting method

Tags: python, scipy, ode

```
def integrate_ode(ode,u0,T):
    sol=solve_ivp(ode,T,u0)
    return sol.y[:,-1]

def phase(ode,u0):
    return ode(0,u0)[0] #dx/dt(0)

def shooting(ode,U):
    print(len(U))
    u0=U[0:-1]
    #print(u0)
    T=U[-1]
    #print(T)
    G=np.concatenate((integrate_ode(ode,u0,T)-u0,phase(ode,u0)))
    return G
```

To get the solutions I'm using:

```
fsolve(lambda U:shooting(ode1,U),...(initial conditions))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Here is my full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  "...Python\workweek16.py", line 62, in <module>
    G=fsolve(lambda U:shooting(ode1,U),(0,0))
  File "C:\Users\tmara\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 160, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Users\tmara\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 226, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "C:\Users\tmara\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 24, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "...Python\workweek16.py", line 62, in <lambda>
    G=fsolve(lambda U:shooting(ode1,U),(0,0))
  File "...Python\workweek16.py", line 51, in shooting
    G=np.concatenate((integrate_ode(ode,u0,T)-u0,phase(ode,u0)))
  File "...Python\workweek16.py", line 40, in integrate_ode
    sol=solve_ivp(ode,T,u0)
  File "C:\Users\tmara\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py", line 508, in solve_ivp
    t0, tf = float(t_span[0]), float(t_span[1])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of your exception? It would also be a good idea to tag the library you're using for your integration.

Comment: @Blckknght I've added the traceback to the question

Comment: I don't know a whole lot about `scipy` (which I've added to your tags), but the docs suggest that `T` needs to be a 2-tuple when you pass it to `solve_ivp`, and the error suggests that you're passing in a scalar instead.

Comment: Wait a minute.  There's a line of code you're not showing us that calls `fsolve`, passing in `integrate_ode` as the function to optimize.  `integrate_ode` then calls `fsolve` again, passing in `ode1`.  Is that REALLY what you meant to do?  `fsolve` calls the function repeatedly with different operands. so this is at least O(N**2).  Doing that nested is going to take a very, very, very long time.  I suspect this is not what you wanted.

Comment: @TimRoberts so what I'm trying to do is to Construct the shooting root-finding problem for the predator-prey example; check that it can find the periodic orbit. I'm not really sure how to do this, I know I have to use the functions that I've given in the question, but no idea how to implement them to get the shooting method running

Answer (score 1):

The `t_span` argument for `solve_ivp` needs to actually be a time span. So replace `T` there with `[0,T]`.